# How to Connect to my Database in Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans

Im having trouble connecting to my Database. I've already activated my Xampp and MySQL. Here is my DriverManager.getConnection:

```
package Genos;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MySQLConnection
{
    public static Connection con;

    public static void connect()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Project","root","root");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Database not found");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Login Form:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM USER "
                + "WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?";

        try 
        {
            MySQLConnection.connect();
            PreparedStatement pst = MySQLConnection.con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1,jTextField1_user.getText());
            pst.setString(2,jPasswordField1_user.getText());
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Successful");
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect username or password");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex + "SQL failed");
            //System.out.println(ex.);
        }

    }
```

I dont know what to do. Is there something wrong w/ my Database? Im using the Database provided by Netbeans btw.

Comment: What is your error output if we may ask?

Comment: You stated using "MySQL" but the JDBC url is for Derby.

Comment: Im using the Netbeans Service Database.

Comment: My Error is NULLPOINTEREXCEPTIONSQL. I thought maybe the Database was not connected

Comment: I suggest u to write api for database if u are using mysql write php api ,to me this is much better

Comment: I dont know what that is. Im actually a noob at this but what i do know is that we are required to use the Services Database in Netbeans. I just dont know why the Database does not connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you have included mysqlconnector.jar at the build path settings.

Comment: Im really sorry good sir but i dont really know what that is. Im using Netbeans service Database.